# libusb1 fails do_configure task with "udev support requested but libudev not installed"

Tags: linux, embedded, configure, libusb, yocto

I'm trying to build a [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html) image.

- I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I've installed the packages the link above recommends (and more)
- I cloned the [poky](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky) git repository, and checked out the [daisy-11.0.0](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tag/?id=daisy-11.0.0) tag.
- `conf/local.conf` has `MACHINE=qemux86`, nearly all other settings are default.
- I tweaked # of threads for bitbake and make.
- `bitbake -k core-image-minimal`

I get the following error during the do_configure task of libusb1_1.0.18.bb:

```
configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"
```

`libudev-dev` is installed.

This seems strange to me because I'm using a plain vanilla no frills setup.

Does anyone know how to resolve this configure error?

I'm not 100% sure this is on-topic for SO. Please direct me to the proper place if so before closing.

Comment: Is it a typo when you say you searched for `libusb` ? It's asking for `libudev`. Is `libudev-dev` installed ?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a typo. `libudev-dev` is installed. I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do a `repo sync`, it has been solved and pushed today (20 may 2014)

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem but in a slightly different environment. I’m just sharing this answer in case it helps you solve your problems.

Anyway, I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and I checked out the latest from git://github.com/openembedded/oe-core.git. I started a build but got the exact same problem. Just like you, I get the following error during the do_configure task of libusb1_1.0.18.bb:

configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"

So I checked the git logs and noticed that that particular recipe was modified on May 15, which was a day before my checkout. I decided to pull out those changes (by checking out the previous commit) and rebuilt the image. It succeeded, which makes me think that update may have broken the build.

Comment: I'll check the logs, but I checked out a release tag, `daisy-11.0.0`.